# add/call widget in default.tpl layout socialengine

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm new in programming zend and socialengine. I have default.tpl layouts like the following:

```
  <body id="global_page_<?php echo $identity ?>">
  <div id="global_header">
    <?php echo $this->content('header') ?>
  </div>
  <div id='global_wrapper'>
    <div id='global_content'>
      <div class="new class contain widget">

      </div>
        <?php //echo $this->content('global-user', 'before') ?>
        <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
        <?php //echo $this->content('global-user', 'after') ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="global_footer">
    <?php echo $this->content('footer') ?>
  </div>
  <div id="janrainEngageShare" style="display:none">Share</div>
</body>
```

I want to add/call widget and place it inside `<div class="new class contain widget"> </div>` tag. For example, I want to add widget menu main and search widget from Core Module inside this html tag, How can I achieve this? Need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple. 
Use the following code, replacing the core.menu-main with name of your widget:

```
<div class="new class contain widget">
    <?php echo $this->content()->renderWidget("core.menu-main"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: how to set configuration for the widget ??